# Having trouble assigning a value to an int

Tags: c#

I'm having trouble assigning a value to the int **PlanPrice**. I've cut out a lot of code, but when the user presses the key "a" the AddCustomer function is called and they can input a lot of data which gets saved without a problem at all. But at the end of the **AddCustomer** function, I use a switch to determine the price of their current plan. However when I try to use the **PlanPrice** int after this function has returned back to Main, the value is always 0. I can see that within the AddCustomer function the value actually does get assigned, but as I go back to the switch in **Main**, for some reason, stays at 0, despite all the other data from the user in AddCustomer actually saving and working properly..

Main:

```
int PlanPrice = 0;
...
switch (menuSelection)
{
     case "a": AddCustomer(..., PlanPrice); break;
     case "c": CalculatePayment(..., PlanPrice); break; //Displays 0
     ...
     case "z": Console.WriteLine(PlanPrice); break; //Displays 0
}
```

AddCustomer:

```
static void AddCustomer(..., int PlanPrice)
{
     ...
     Console.Write("Current Plan (S, M, L or XL): ");
     currentPlan[arrayLength] = Console.ReadLine();
     switch (currentPlan[arrayLength]) 
     {
         case "S": { planPrice = 55; } break;
         case "M": { planPrice = 70; } break;
         case "L": { planPrice = 95; } break;
         case "XL": { planPrice = 135; } break;
         default:
         {
             Console.WriteLine("\nSorry, you can only enter S, M, L or XL\n");  
         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your method needs to modify a parameter, it must be flagged as either `out` or `ref`.

```
static void AddCustomer(..., out int PlanPrice)
{
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Option 1**

Pass `PlanPrice` by [`ref`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx) or [`out`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx.aspx)

> The out keyword causes arguments to be passed by reference. This is
>   like the ref keyword, except that ref requires that the variable be
>   initialized before it is passed. To use an out parameter, both the
>   method definition and the calling method must explicitly use the out
>   keyword.

So it seems in your case, `out` fits better

```
static void AddCustomer(..., out int PlanPrice)
{
   ... 
}
```

**Option 2**

Because your `AddCustomer` is static, Another alternative you can use in your case, is making `PlanPrice` to be `static`, Then you don't need `PlanPrice` to be a parameter of `AddCustomer`:

```
static int PlanPrice;

static void AddCustomer(...)
{
   //PlanPrice is accessible here, because it is static and your method is static too.
}
```